# Convert “probability X to occur each period”, to “next occurence in F(random, X) seconds”

Tags: language-agnostic, probability, frequency-distribution

To replace an existing algorithm “every period N compare a random number to probability X”, what is the correct function `F` to instead compute a random *delay* until the next occurrence?

I want to re-write an existing function. Pseudocode:

```pseudo
interval_step ← (N milliseconds)
Every (interval_step):
    If random() < X:
        event_occurs()
```

So the event can occur (with `X` probability) at `N` milliseconds at the earliest. There is no upper bound on the latest when the event could occur, but larger multiples of `N` get increasingly unlikely.

My mathematics skill is not good enough to tell what formula describes this. I think this is a geometric progression, maybe a logarithmic one?

The new implementation should instead produce an equivalent distribution of event occurrences across time, but without the polling loop. Instead I want to set a timer to a random interval computed from `X`. Pseudocode:

```pseudo
interval_step = (N milliseconds)
schedule(fire_event, interval=random_interval_to_next_event())

random_interval_to_next_event():
    interval ← F(random_number=random(), probability=X)
    Return interval

fire_event():
    schedule(fire_event, interval=random_interval_to_next_event())
    event_occurs()
```

This avoids the polling loop of the original, by pre-calculating each occurrence for a single random time (computed by the function `F`) in the future, still using increments of `interval_step`.

I'd be happy enough to set an arbitrary upper bound somewhere inside `F` (maybe based on some high number of standard deviations from `X`) to avoid a potentially-infinite function call. I'd be just as happy to avoid it if that would be needless complication.

(In response to a discussion) I am also happy to assume a truncated precision, to effectively limit the asymptotically small probabilities at the long tail. Assume the existence of a function `truncate_precision(number, precision_digits=12)` that would allow something like:

```
F(random_number, probability):
    foo ← (random_number * truncate_precision(SOME_CALCULATION))
    Return foo
```

or the like. This avoids underflow for very low probabilities.

What is the correct implementation of the function `F` to get the equivalent probability distribution `X` of the original?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
F(random_number, probability):
   return milliseconds * floor(log(1-random_number)/log(probability)) + 1
```

This works by considering that your initial solution has a `probability` probability of sleeping each iteration of the loop, giving overall an sleep of `N * milliseconds` milliseconds for the `N`th iteration. So sleeping for `N * milliseconds` has a `probability ** N` probability of occuring, where `**` denotes exponentiation.

If we roll a random number once, we can find the smallest probability power that's still larger than the random number, and that would indicate which iteration the loop would have broken in your original solution. To do this, we solve the following equation for `N`, and then floor it.

```
random_number = probability ** N
```

using the change of base formula-

```
N = log(random_number) / log(probability)
```

But most random number generators use a range of `[0, 1)`, meaning we may have to evaluate `log(0)`, which is not defined, so we invert that range to `(0, 1]` by subtracting `random_number` from 1. Lastly, we add 1 since we always want to sleep at least `milliseconds` milliseconds. This gives us the final result for iterations to sleep `N` being-

```
floor(log(1-random_number)/log(probability)) + 1
```

Note that because of finite precision, you're capped in the maximum possible delay because `random_number` can only get so small due to finite precision. It also relies heavily on your RNG being uniform.

Comment: That's interesting. It seems that, given an input parameter `random_number`, the calculation should be entirely formulaic. Can that be re-written so that the calculation is not done in a loop?

Comment: Yes: `N=round(log(random_numer)/log(probability))+1` or something similar should do it, but you'll again run into the finite precision issue.

Comment: if you edit the answer to remove the loop, I'd like to up-vote.

Comment: I updated the answer to use the closed-form equation for the first option, but left the second in case anyone else who finds this would prefer a workaround option for the finite precision issue. Note that I also changed `random_number` to `1-random_number` to prevent the occasional `log(0)` exception.

Comment: I've edited the question to allow for an existing `truncate_precision` function, to explicitly work around the issue you describe. Does that help refine this answer?

Comment: I'd find this easier to follow if we were discussing just one answer in each thread. Can you put the second part into a separate answer that can be discussed separately?

Comment: The `round(log(1 - random_number) / log(probability))` part seems always destined to produce either `1` or `0` (because the argument will always be a number between 0 and 1). Is that a mistake, or am I missing something?

Comment: I have updated the answer move the second solution to its own answer, and to elaborate on the formula for this solution

Comment: Thank you. Note that the `probability` is the (original implementation's) probability that the event will *occur* each time through the loop; that seems to be the opposite sense from what you've interpreted.

Comment: Another note: the original implementation has a loop that never breaks, it loops forever. Each time through the event may occur (with `probability` probability). The goal is to find a way to calculate the duration until the next occurrence, without the loop.

Comment: Imagine that you modify your original code to instead of drawing a new random number each time you loop, take the (unassumingly uniform) range of [0, probability) and scale it up to [0, 1) by multiplication. The number of iterations reflects how close the random number was to 0, in an identical fashion to my implementation, however remains functionally equivalent to yours.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution if you are looking for a more precise answer that isn't limited by hardware precision, you can use something like the following.

```
F(probability):
   N = 1
   while random() < probability
       N += 1
   return milliseconds * N
```

This will in theory allow for any duration delay, with no upper bound.